# how do I select only numeric value from a column which has numeric, string and empty value in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

Text Column in `TestTable` has

```
1,,9876,12a3,00a1,3333,7777,ABCD,EFGH
```

I would like return any number or text which is in numeric digits.

My query is

```
SELECT "Test" FROM "MyTable" 
WHERE "Test" not like '%[^0-9]%' and "Test" != '';
```

Query returns `1,9876,12a3,00a1,3333,7777,ABCD,EFGH`.

What I want is `1,9876,3333,7777`

Comment: You can use regex to test like: `"Test" ~ '^[0-9]*$'` or `"Test" !~ '[^0-9]|^$` which would catch that `''` non-null blank.

Comment: This works. Thank you